# why does "for month, days in (calender or calendar)" return ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)? python

Tags: python

i have been trying to print two different calendars ('calender', and 'calendar') in this code; the difference in the two lists is one is a leap year and the other is not. i have been working on it for a few days and reading all the documentation i can but for some reason this code keeps returning the following error:

> for month, days in (calender or calendar):
>
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

it is expecting 2 values which i provided 2 values and it still will not run.

```
    import numpy as np
    import itertools

    calendar =  [('month0', range(1, 37, + 1)),
                ('leap month 37,', range(37, 1, + 1)),
                ('month2      ', range(70, 70, + 1)),
                ('month3   ', range(71, 74, + 1)),   #keep 74 it makes the 70-73 show up
                ('month4     ', range(38, 74, + 1))]

   calender =   [('month0', range(1, 37, + 1)),
                ('Month1', range(37, 1, + 1)),
                ('month2   ', range(38, 71, + 1)),
                ('month3   ', range(71, 74, + 1))]
    
    def make_calendar(year, start_day):
        week = ['Mer', 'Ven', 'Ear', 'Mar', 'Jup', 'Sat', 'Ura', 'Nep', 'Plu']
        start_pos = week.index(start_day)
        def leapyr(n):
            if n % 400 == 0:
                return True
            if n % 100 == 0:
                return False
            if n % 4 == 0:
                return True
                print(calendar)
            else:
                print(calender)
        for month, days in (calender, calendar):
            # Print month title
            print('{0} {1}'.format(month, year).center(20, ' '))
            # Print Day headings
            print(''.join(['{0:<3}'.format(w) for w in week]))
            # Add spacing for non-zero starting position
            print('{0:<3}'.format('')*start_pos, end='')
    
            for day in days:
                # Print day
                print('{0:<3}'.format(day), end='')
                start_pos += 1
                if start_pos == 9:
                    # If start_pos == 9 (Sunday) start new line
                    print()
                    start_pos = 0 # Reset counter
            print('\n')
    start_day=(input('Enter start day of the year Mer,Ven,Ear,Mar,Jup,Sat,Ura,Nep,Plu'))
    year=int(input('Enter Year')),          
    make_calendar(year, start_day)
```

edit***
i edited the following lines

```
>   for month, days in zip(calenderB, calendarA):

> for day in days:
> # Print day
> print('{0!s:<3}'.format(day), end='')
```

code is printing "calender" and "calendar" seperatly thankfully thanks to @Pedro

however it prints looking like this

```
> Enter start day of the year Mer,Ven,Ear,Mar,Jup,Sat,Ura,Nep,PluMer
> Enter Year2020 ('Early Winter', range(1, 37)) (2020,)
> MerVenEarMarJupSatUraNepPlu month0range(1, 37)
> 
> (leap month, range(37, 1)) (2020,) MerVenEarMarJupSatUraNepPlu
>       Mid Winter 37,range(37, 1)
> 
> ('month2   ', range(38, 71)) (2020,) MerVenEarMarJupSatUraNepPlu
>             Late Winter   range(38, 71)
> 
> ('month3', range(71, 74)) (2020,) MerVenEarMarJupSatUraNepPlu
>                   Leap Day      range(70, 70)
```

it is printing the list items as a string rather than code.

it is desired to look more like this>

```
Enter start day of the year Mer,Ven,Ear,Mar,Jup,Sat,Ura,Nep,PluMer
Enter Year2019
month1 (2019,)
MerVenEarMarJupSatUraNepPlu
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36


month2 (2019,)
MerVenEarMarJupSatUraNepPlu
...

month3    (2019,)
MerVenEarMarJupSatUraNepPlu
...
```

etc.

Comment: because `(calendar, calendar)` creates a list with two elements each of the calendar objects, when you iterate over with with `for` you get the elements one at a time. I think you meant to just concatenate the lists: `for month, day in calender+calendar:`. Also, name your variables better this is confusing.

Comment: is it possible to print one ""Calendar"" at a time rather than 'calender' and 'calendar' printing at the same time? also thanks for the tip on the confusion you are right im going to edit them to calendarA and calendarB now that you mentioned it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop over two lists at the same time, you have to use the zip() function, like this:

```
for month, days in zip(calender, calendar):
    #code
```

You can pass as many lists as you wish as argument to zip, as long as you loop with the same number of variables (e.g. 3 lists, 3 variables). If the lists don't all have the same size, zip stops at the end of the shortest.

Comment: thank you, your code prints the calendars! however it prints both rather than one or the other?
i tried using def leapyr(n),
to either>>> 
if 
return True 
print(calendAr)  
else print(calendEr)
but your code snippet takes both and prints them both. ill figure it out hopefully

Comment: What do you mean, do you want to alternate between both? How do you want to choose between calender and calendar?

Comment: thanks for the speedy reply. i am trying to use that code i just commented to result in one or the other. the snippet of code you shared worked but it prints both. somehow its not recognizing the if else statements.

Comment: Oh, then I think you should nest the if condition in the loop I mentioned. Something like: if leapyr(n): #print appropriate calendar else: #print what you want to print. This way you have access to both calendars and the if condition can just "pick" the right one.

Comment: error code cone but now its printing incorrenctly its calendar as a string of text

Comment: ok @Pedro Puglia  the code is working but is printing. i updated the question to show the update to the errors produced from the code you mentioned. its working a lot better but its printing odd. i appreciate your help.

Comment: Now I think you just have to tweak the print statement. Maybe use some more string formatting (the documentation is of great help here) or make use of the optional keyword arguments for print, like sep and end.